# How to draw a for e.g. a grass ground in texture paint within blender 2.8?

Tags: texture-painting

So I wanted to draw a gras ground on a plane, but I don't know what i have to change in the Texture Slots and Texture Panel, maybe someone can help me?
 [image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tiT1.png)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have it almost ready - under Texture in the Properties Panel tool settings, leave the image brush set to Tiled but make your brush a white color and full strength.
[image]